# Is it appropriate to refer to the "height" of a function?

Tags: calculus, terminology

I need to point out that a certain process will have an effect on the average "height" (i.e.: the average value of the function in the y axis) of a 1-dimensional function.

Is it correct to say that "*the process A will decrease the average height of the function*". Is there a more appropriate term for this?

Comment: What's the height of a function?

Comment: I mean the "average y value". I'll ad this to the question, sorry.

Comment: Calling it "mean" would be more appropriate.

Comment: It would be more appropriate to refer to this, as you say, as the "average value."

Comment: I don't think "height" is standard terminology (a google search did not turn up any examples).  "Average" or "mean" are perfectly good.  Specify $y-$value if you feel the context warrants that.

Comment: I would think referring to the "average value" rather than the "average height" is better. You even use this term in your parenthetical explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would only use it, if the function values are physical heights, like in the case below.

[image: Height profile Andes] ([Large Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRCFW.gif))